# PEDA: Don't show context

Tags: debugging, gdb, python, dynamic-analysis

`gdb-peda` shows a very useful context each time it stops (`b`, `si`, etc.), but sometimes I don't want it.  Is there any way to quiet it so it won't show the context automatically (unless prompted `context`)?

--

## UPDATE

Since there's no out of the box answer, I'll take, for the bounty, a custom or roll-your-own solution (e.g. a script or special command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing through peda's source, it seems to use a gdb hook-stop, which can be modified back and forth:

```
gdb-peda$ show user hook-stop
User command "hook-stop":
  peda context
  session autosave

gdb-peda$ define hook-stop
Type commands for definition of "hook-stop".
End with a line saying just "end".
>session autosave
>end
gdb-peda$ n
18        printf("...");
gdb-peda$ define hook-stop
Type commands for definition of "hook-stop".
End with a line saying just "end".
>peda context
>session autosave
>end
gdb-peda$ n
[---registers---]
EAX: 0x0
EBX: 0x56557000 --> 0x1ef8
```

Relevant source is at https://github.com/longld/peda/blob/84d38bda505941ba823db7f6c1bcca1e485a2d43/peda.py#L6120 and https://github.com/longld/peda/blob/84d38bda505941ba823db7f6c1bcca1e485a2d43/peda.py#L230 .

I'd imagine there's a way to extend peda, so that the `peda` object's methods can be called, but I can't figure that out.  In the absence of that, we can invoke those commands manually.  Note that gdb doesn't seem to allow nested `define`s, so we can't script the (re)`define`s themselves.